# Printing png is pixelated

Tags: printing, qpainter, qprinter

I have some text and an R.png file.
These i want to print to a PDF-file and to a "real" printer.

I do that with the following code:

```
draw(QPainter *Painter)
{   
R_img = QImage("c:/R.png"); 
Painter->drawImage(0, 0, R_img.scaled(100, 100, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
Painter->drawEllipse(QRect(2, 60, 20, 10));

QFont font = Painter->font();
font.setPixelSize(10);
Painter->setFont(font);
Painter->drawText(2, 100,"my Text");
}

...
// saving as *.pdf
QPrinter pdfprinter;
pdfprinter.setOutputFileName("c:/test.pdf");
QPainter pdfPainter(&pdfprinter);
draw(&pdfPainter);

// printing to "real" printer
QPrinter printer;
printer.setPrinterName("FreePDF");

QPainter printPainter(&printer);
draw(&printPainter);
...
```

That works fine except for the pixelated R.png file.

I was trying to solve the Problem by adding the following line to the draw method:

```
R_img.setDevicePixelRatio(5);
Painter->drawImage(0, 0, R_img.scaled(500, 500, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation));
```

After that the created pdf looks fine, but the printed file still is pixelated. Please look at the attached images "printed pdf with setDevicePixelRatio" and "created pdf with setDevicePixelRatio".

Could anybody give me please some idea what i am doing wrong here?

I tried to solve that problem by changing the resolution in my printerdriver but that didn't work. For me the weird thing is that the Elipse looks just fine in every case.

Unfortunatelly the attached R.png is just an example to demonstrate my Problem. It can not be replaced by drawing just text.

Thanks for you help in advance!

[printed pdf with setDevicePixelRatio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40c5O.png)
[created pdf with setDevicePixelRatio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZGJ6.png)